# How can I make a Text and a Button on the same level

Tags: react-native

I'm new to react-native and using flex box, I normally use Grid supplied by bootstrap or other css frameworks.

I'm trying to get the word **Settings** in the middle and my **down arrow** 
on the right side to toggle away the modal but all I can get is this:

[image]

React code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Text, View } from 'react-native'
import { styles } from './styles'
import ViewContainer from 'Reddit/app/components/ViewContainer'
import StatusBarBg from 'Reddit/app/components/StatusBarBg'
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/EvilIcons'

class SettingsIndexScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ViewContainer>
        <StatusBarBg />
        <View style={styles.collapseIconContainer}>
          <Text>Settings</Text>
          <Icon name="arrow-down" size={40} />
        </View>
      </ViewContainer>
    )
  }
}

export default SettingsIndexScreen
```

css:

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native'

export const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  collapseIcon: {

  },
  toolbar: {
    flexDirection: 'column'
  },
  toolbarTitle: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 20
  },
  toolbarButton: {
    textAlign: 'right',
    marginRight: 8
  }
});
```

Can't seem to figure out how to get them on the same level

Answer (score 1):

This should give you some idea -

```
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={styles.row}>
      <View style={styles.col1}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>Text1</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.col2}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>Text2</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  </View>
```

-

```
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  row: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  col1: {
    flex: 0.6,
  },
  col2: {
    flex: 0.4,
  },
  text: {
    textAlign: 'right',
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `flexDirection: 'row'` in their parent container -- `collapseIconContainer`, like so

```
collapseIconContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row';
}
```